# How do I fix a corrupted supervise?

Tags: daemontools

Our set up is such that we have `supervise` directories linked to our source control. Unfortunately, if we change branches without bringing down services first, it breaks `supervise`.

```
$ sudo svstat /service/ppma
/service/ppma: unable to read supervise/status: bad format
```

I can't find any information about that error, or how to fix it. What do I need to do?

Comment: Are there any source control helper files in the ppma folder hierarchy?  Like .git or .cvs files, say.  basically anything that supervise might misinterpret as a file it needs to look at and then choke on.

Comment: Nope. There are none.